# Converting readable date and time to Unixtime

Tags: python

My dataframe.
Name : sdc5.
data it holds,
Type : str

```
0
2019-01-26 13:30:00.000
1
2019-01-16 12:00:00.000
2
2019-02-09 16:00:00.000
3
2019-01-11 17:00:00.000
4
2019-01-28 10:30:00.000
```

I tried to convert this column to unixtime. But it's fires error.

ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

```
pd.to_datetime(sdc5, format='%Y%m%d %H%M%s')

pd.to_datetime(sdc5, format='%Y%m%d %H%M%s')
```

The column with unixtime

Comment: you also need to specify the `-` and `:` between the date parts in the format string

Comment: hmmm.. wonder if I start searching how many of these similar questions I find. Have you tried and if so... post a few links of  them into your question and reason why they didn't work for you. This shows effort and prevents downvoting to get your question removed from SO.

Comment: after checking the same, I have used 'format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'. But it's not useful.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`.

all parts of the string must be either captured by a pattern, or as a literal char.

what you missed:

- the `-` between date parts and `:` between hour parts
- the `.` and `%f` pattern to capture the millisecond part
- using `%S` (capital S) for seconds.

the docs with all the patterns can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior